# How Does Module Loading Work with TypeScript

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, if I am targeting a browser, how does module loading work? Can I use require.js to load modules? does it have it's own loader?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

TypeScript does not provide a runtime. You need to supply a module loader to use, such as requirejs. A TypeScript module can either be generated to CommonJS convention (for use with node.js) or AMD convention (as used in requirejs); which it generates is a compiler switch.

Comment: That is beyond awesome and exactly what I would hope! Can you point me to documentation on how to use the compiler to generate code for use with require.js? Also...if you are looking for a really wicked case study...converting from js to TypeScript...I'd love to show you some stuff.

Comment: Once installed, type tsc -help. It explains the --module option.

Comment: Thank you again. Great work. Really nice stuff...I appreciate the approach that has been taken.

Comment: @EisenbergEffect! I am smelling like there is another awesome piece of software being written for Web, Like AWESOME caliburn.micro.

Answer (score 1):

As Chuckj mentioned, TypeScript does not provide a runtime. You need to supply a module loader to use.

What you then need to do is to tell the TypeScript compiler to generate the JS to confirm with the module loader that would be used at runtime.

You can do this by specifying the module loader to the compiler using -m compiler flag:

```
tsc -m commonjs //'amd', 'system', 'umd' or 'es2015'
```

or by specifying the module in the `compilerOptions` in your `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "commonjs" //'amd', 'system', 'umd' or 'es2015'
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```