# How to execute separated .ts files on tsc?

Tags: typescript, tsc

I made two TypeScript files `A.ts` and `TestA.ts`.

#### A.ts

```
class A {
    constructor( private name : string ){}
    disp(){ console.log( this.name ); }
}
```

#### TestA.ts

```
/// <reference path="A.ts"/>
var a1 = new A( "Jun" );
a1.disp();
```

- `tsc TestA.ts`
  OK. It makes A.js and TestA.js.
- `tsc TestA.ts -e`
  NG. "RefenceError: `A` is not defined"
- `tsc A.ts TestA.ts -e`
  also raises the same error

Where do I go wrong?

Answer (score 4):

`/// <reference path="A.ts"/>` is only used at compile time to reference types in another file. When you use this construct, TypeScript assumes that those types will somehow already be available at runtime. That is, you are responsible for loading them yourself.

What you are wanting to do is reference the other files at *runtime*. This is done using modules and the `import` and `export` keywords.

Try this:

**A.ts**

```
export class A {   
  constructor(private name : string ) {}
  disp() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}
```

**TestA.ts**

```
import a = module('./a');
var a1 = new a.A( "Jun" );
a1.disp();
```

Then you can use `tsc TestA.ts -e` to compile and execute the code.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's solved! But I had to append a 'export' keyword to start of A.ts file. ex. export class A { ....

Answer (score 1):

You have a side error in your code (missing a ")"). This one compiles :

```
class A {   
  constructor(private name : string ) {}
  disp() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}
```

EDIT :

Concerning your initial prob, you need to export the first module then import it in your second file.

**You will need to use an external module loader (like RequireJS) in order to be able to execute it as the compiler will implement a require function call (like CommonJS module).**

see : [How Does Module Loading Work with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12681155/how-does-module-loading-work-with-typescript)

A.ts

```
export class A {
  constructor(private name : string ){}
  disp() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}
```

TestA.js

```
var A = require("./A")
var a1 = new A.A("Jun");
a1.disp();
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That's my mistake. X( But the issue is left unsolved... How should I do to execute multiple .ts files on tsc?